# Setting Session State - APEX 21.1

Tags: oracle-apex

Based on the documentation and examples I have come across, it seems that the way to set/pass session state between pages is via the URL. It got me thinking, is it ok to reference page items from a different page directly? Or are there downsides in doing this that someone new to APEX (like me) may not be aware of initially.

For example:

- there is an app with two pages `PAGE 1` and `PAGE 2`
- `PAGE 1` sets `P1_SOME_VALUE = 'GREEN'` (`P1_SOME_VALUE` now in session state)
- `PAGE 2` needs access to `P1_SOME_VALUE`'s value

Are there any reasons to not set up a `BEFORE HEADER` Computation on `PAGE 2` that sets `P2_SOME_VALUE = :P1_SOME_VALUE`? (Assuming that `P1_SOME_VALUE` is a given to always be available in the session for `PAGE 2`)

If going from `PAGE 1` to `PAGE 2` is done using a hyperlink, then I understand it is easier to set the session state using the REDIRECT URL attribute method that I have seen. I have come across a situation in my app where a URL is generated dynamically after a chain of dynamic actions and using the `BEFORE HEADER` Computation seems like the cleaner/simpler solution for my given situation. Just want to make sure I am not overlooking anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you describe, using a pl/sql process which references a page item from another page will work fine, but there are some things to take into account. Not sure if this list is exhaustive, others might comment:

- Personally I try to avoid references to items on other pages within a page, because that makes developing harder - when working on page x, you'll usually search for item occurences *within page only* . If there are occurences on other pages the application becomes less clean. I try to follow this as a best practice. The cleaner the app, the easier to maintain. When you have to work in this app 2 years from now, you won't remember that `P1_SOME_VALUE` is referenced on page 2. Or that other developer who works on it will hate you forever ;)
- This can possibly make debugging a lot harder. Suppose page is accessed via a url or branch that has the option "clear cache for pages" set to "page 1", then the value of `P1_SOME_VALUE` will be cleared because that item is defined on page 1. Debugging this issue will be a challenge.
- Passing a value in a url is very secure. If you use checksums, there is no way for a user to manipulate the value of the page item manually.
- Note that the DOM of the page only contains the page items that are defined on that page. This implies that you cannot use javascript on page 2 that references `P1_SOME_VALUE` or set the value of `P1_SOME_VALUE` using javascript on page 2. This doesn't matter in your use case.

An alternative to referencing page items in another page than the page they belong to is storing the data in a collection - that will exist for the duration of the session.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Would my example above be a good use for an APPLICATION_ITEM instead (set on one page, but can be used in other pages)? I will read about collections. Are collections an APEX API?

Comment: In general, using an url is the way to go. An application item will work too, note that that is not in the DOM either. APEX_COLLECTIONS is a pl/sql API: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeapi/APEX_COLLECTION.html#GUID-859B488C-2628-44D7-969F-50872C685B76

Comment: i used the URL initially, but the value being shared is a 'temp pswd' and it was recommended to not pass that kind of info with the url. `PAGE 2` is a confirmation page letting user now their password has been reset.

Comment: Why would you pass the value of such a sensitive datapoint to another page at all ? On page 1 execute a page process to store the password and let the user know the password has been changed on page 2. Don't bother displaying it - I have never seen the confirmation "successfully changed your pwd to foobar" :)

Comment: understood and agree 100%, but customer requests a manual process which I have fought to switch - suggesting it be automated by adding a process that sends an email after the reset password page process completes. regardless, i appreciate your insight...

Comment: No prob. Customer pays - can't argue with that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235334/discussion-between-mcrivers-and-koen-lostrie).