# Using APEX_COLLECTIONS with Large or Multi-Page Forms - APEX 21.1

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm in the process of mocking / designing an Application form that consists of many regions that will be broken out across 5 pages (I'm intentionally not using the APEX Wizard Component due to personal choice and given requirements). So I will need to store/persist all the pages' information temporarily, while user fills out the form and reviews and saves their application on the last page.

Based on a response to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68530516/setting-session-state-apex-21-1), it seems that `apex_collections` are the preferred way to do this versus using the values already in `session state` to persist the information during the session. I've spent a bit of time breaking the form into logical groups of data that can be mapped to about 8 collections.

Questions:

- Is this a correct assumption (collections vs session state) and approach?
- Are there any performance considerations to think of when using `APEX_COLLECTIONS` (esp. if using 2 or 3 per page)?
- How is it best to handle both the values in Session state along with the the collections? Assuming you utilize the session state values to populate the page items on their associated forms, but use the collections for the last page when you save? So you are kind of maintaining the data twice, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections is definitely a very solid solution. I don't think you'll see any performance issues, under the hood all collections are stored in a single table anyway.

Personally I would not rely on session data when navigating between the different steps of a wizard flow (doesn't matter if that is the apex component or not) if you are also using collections.

Instead have 2 sets of Processes for each page/collection

1. A page process before rendering to fetch the data from each collection if it exists
2. A page process after submit to insert/update the data of each collection

Comment: As always thanks @Koen, a small wrinkle I just realized. I will need to reference page item values from "previous" pages throughout the 'wizard flow' so I can build dynamic actions that would affect how other pages are presented to the user. For example, on page 1 if P1_FORM_TYPE = 221 then on page 2, I would hide/show certain regions and page items based on the value of P1_FORM_TYPE. Assuming, I just add an APPLICATION_ITEM or PAGE_ITEM for those values needed and load them on rendering page process?

Comment: Sure you can - best to do is to not reference a page item from another page - that can lead to very unexpected behaviour. Instead pass them back and forth using branches/links. So in your case you'd have a P2_FORM_TYPE on page 2 that is set by a branch on page 1. That is the way I do things - others might have different opinions.